# Posterior probability of an image when the posterior of local features are known

Tags: machine-learning, probability, conditional-probability, computer-vision

Lets assume the local features $x_1, x_2, \dots x_n$ of an image $I$ are independent.

I know if $p(x_i|c)$ are given $p(I|c)$ can be defined by $\prod_{i=1}^N x_i$

But I dont know how to calculate the posterior $p(c|I)$ when $p(c|x_i)$ are known ($c$ is a class)

Answer (score 1):

Use Bayes' rule:

$p(c|I) = {p(I|c) p(c) \over p(I)}$

where

$p(I) = \sum\limits_{c=1}^N p(I|c)$ .